# why cant i install xubuntu using wubi installer?

Tags: installation, wubi, xubuntu

I have tried a couple times to install Xubuntu using WUBI. All I get is this error:

```
An error occurred:
    Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO
    For more information please see log file:
    c:\User\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev269.log
```

please help!!!

Comment: i would gess there's something blocking the download (firewall?). Try to download manually the .iso from [Get Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/), save it in the same folder where WUBI installer is and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Since 12.10, Xubuntu was removed from Wubi by the request of the Xubuntu project lead. It's no longer possible to install Xubuntu, except with an elaborate workaround.

You can still use Xubuntu with 12.04.1 wubi.exe but that also requires a workaround to install due to a bug: only possible with wubi.exe 12.04.1 and xubuntu desktop iso 12.04.1 in the same folder.

bcbc- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1961647

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install a previous Xubuntu version on Wubi, then updated until I got to 12.10. Time consuming, but for those who do not want to partition a hard drive, it can be done.